# HtmlTextWriter create <a> tag

Tags: vb.net, htmltextwriter

How can I add target used HtmlTextWriter . I need the  target='_blank'. Would some one help me.

there is the code:

```
Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
Using ht As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                    ht.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A)
                    ht.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, "Order" & "/" & "FileName")
                    ht.Write("Order1")
                    ht.RenderEndTag()
 End Using
```

Comment: I found the solution. I need this code,  ht.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Target, "_blank")

Answer (score 1):

I need this code, ht.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Target, "_blank")